# How to use multiple SQL commands in one query in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an SQL command in my query in Excel. I'm not sure if this is possible, but can you put 2 commands in 1 query? I have:

```
SELECT TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY), TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT
FROM WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR 
GROUP BY TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT
```

and

```
SELECT TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD
WHERE (TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD = "PUT")
```

I got this code to work separately, but I don't know how to combine them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Do you want all four fields included in the output but only where (TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD = "PUT")

Comment: @RobAnthony yes!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY), TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD
FROM WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR
WHERE (TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD = "PUT")
GROUP BY TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD
```

You should be able to shorten this to:

```
SELECT LOGON_ID, SUM(FULL_PLLT_QTY), SHIFT_DT, PRI_GRP_CD
FROM TALLY_TRAN_MSTR
WHERE (PRI_GRP_CD = "PUT")
GROUP BY LOGON_ID, SHIFT_DT, PRI_GRP_CD
```

Comment: it comes up with an error message saying "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Is there ONE table called TALLY_TRAN_MSTR and it has fields LOGON_ID, SHIFT_DT, FULL_PLLT_QTY, PRI_GRP_CD (not necessarily in that order)?

Comment: yes it all comes from that same table from the database I'm pulling from.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, can you paste the code you are using into the question so that I can see how you are doing it. The SQL should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, SUM(TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.FULL_PLLT_QTY), TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT
FROM WBR_RW.TALLY_TRAN_MSTR 
GROUP BY TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.LOGON_ID, TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.SHIFT_DT
HAVING (TALLY_TRAN_MSTR.PRI_GRP_CD = "PUT")
```